# Can't get GStreamer ON when installing OpenCV from source

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to use GStreamer with OpenCV on Python, so I follow the instructions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-beta/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) to install OpenCV from source. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

I used the following cmake command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") \
-DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
-DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
-DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
-DWITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

The end of the output after this command is

```
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               4.7.0-45-g4d918ba40b
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2023-01-27T20:04:05Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.16.3
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (18 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (34 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (8 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching ts video videoio
--     Disabled:                    python2 world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI:                           GTK3
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.6)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.1.0)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_3)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
--       avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.3)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/user/install_opencv/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                /home/user/install_opencv/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     VA:                          NO
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/user/install_opencv/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.10)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.10)
--     numpy:                       /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.23.4)
--     install path:                /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/install_opencv/opencv/build
```

But after finishing the install, what I get from `python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())"` is

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.7.0-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-12-29T19:08:51Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-1023-azure x86_64
    CMake:                       3.25.0
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (32 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.2.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /lib64/libopenblas.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /usr/local/lib/libpng.so /usr/local/lib/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:                           QT5
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0 )
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/local/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/local/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (59.37.100)
      avformat:                  YES (59.27.100)
      avutil:                    YES (57.28.100)
      swscale:                   YES (6.7.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      YES (/lib64/libopenblas.so)
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7 (ver 3.7.16)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.7m.a (ver 3.7.16)
    numpy:                       /home/ci/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            /bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

where GSTREAMER if NO.

Am I looking to two different OpenCV versions? I did uninstall old OpenCV versions before installing with `pip uninstall opencv-python` and `sudo make uninstall` in the build folder of the previous version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build opencv for python3, you may try adjusting like:

```
cmake 
...
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python2) \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
...
```